# Getting different result (cyphertext) while using AES in Java and golang

Tags: java, go, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to replicate the java code for AES encryption into Golang.
However I am not getting the same output in golang

I tried below code:

**Java Code:**

```
package EncryptionTest;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptionDecryptionAES {

    static Cipher cipher;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Key secretKey;
        secretKey = (Key)new SecretKeySpec("0123456789012345".getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        String plainText = "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption";
        System.out.println("Plain Text Before Encryption: " + plainText);
        String encryptedText = encrypt(plainText, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);
        String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text After Decryption: " + decryptedText);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, Key secretKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, Key secretKey) throws Exception {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

**Java code output:**
*Plain Text Before Encryption: AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption
Encrypted Text After Encryption: vSmrgH3qU+qEq+3ui0YvwCa6PDBcMyhgOlbh3+zzM+cON6feLk2u1iPW7lITD3vn
Decrypted Text After Decryption: AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption*

**Golang Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

const NONCESIZE = 12

func main() {
    key := []byte("0123456789012345")
    plaintext := []byte("AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption")
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    nonce := make([]byte, NONCESIZE)
    aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    ciphertext := aesgcm.Seal(nil, nonce, plaintext, nil)
    fmt.Println("Encrypted Text is : ", base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext))

}
```

**Golang Code output:**
*Encrypted Text is :  7UMh49c5Wqb2BzlttKBEnq5g4fxMK9oJs1EUDIgWzVwlY28k+qd/oFG9SJckBsaX6DHp*

Comment: Java's getBytes is not deterministic but depends on the default charset.

Comment: AES use random initial vector for encryption. Every call generates random initial vector and this cause different encrypted text.

Comment: @DogushanKAYA : The code which I pasted here, generating the same encrypted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the go code, you are using AES in GCM mode with 12 bytes of zero as IV, but in java code you are using default mode of AES which is not the same in different java versions.

By using GCM mode(Provided in BouncyCastle) and setting the same IV(12 bytes of zero) I got same output:

```
package EncryptionTest;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptionDecryptionAES {

    static Cipher cipher;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());


        Key secretKey;
        secretKey = (Key)new SecretKeySpec("0123456789012345".getBytes(), "AES");

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");

        String plainText = "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption";
        System.out.println("Plain Text Before Encryption: " + plainText);
        String encryptedText = encrypt(plainText, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);
        String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text After Decryption: " + decryptedText);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, Key secretKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes();


        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

        byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, Key secretKey) throws Exception {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);

        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

        byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Plain Text Before Encryption: AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption
Encrypted Text After Encryption: 7UMh49c5Wqb2BzlttKBEnq5g4fxMK9oJs1EUDIgWzVwlY28k+qd/oFG9SJckBsaX6DHp
Decrypted Text After Decryption: AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption
```

Comment: Here I want to know what is the default mode which my java code is using and how to replicate the same in golang.

Comment: @PrashantGupta relying on default mode is risky. You should set it explicitly. As I said, you can use GCM in golang and java but if you don't want to use bouncy castle, you can use CBC mode in both languages.